# Get media url in View in Sitecore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, sitecore, media

I have a mp3 file that is stored in the media library. It is referenced in a media field on an item. I can get the URL by doing Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaURL() in webforms or a class. But how can I achieve this in a MVC view? When I dump the field it just renders a html tag. I want to pull out the url only.

Also, is there a reference for something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write an extension method to get the media item URL.  Something like this will work (you should add null reference checks btw):

```
public static string GetMediaUrl(this Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper sitecoreHelper, string fieldName)
{
    return GetMediaUrl(sitecoreHelper, fieldName, sitecoreHelper.CurrentItem);
}

public static string GetMediaUrl(this Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper sitecoreHelper, string fieldName, Item item)
{
    ImageField imageField = item.Fields[fieldName];
    return Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);
}
```

In your cshtml files you can then use:

```
<a href="@Html.Sitecore().GetMediaUrl("YourMediaField")">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Now this is something I can get behind. Reusability.

Comment: @Gabbar Note that the `SitecoreHelper` isn't used in `GetMediaUrl`, but it looks to a consumer like it is. That could create future confusion.

Comment: Where does `GetMediaUrl` go though?

Comment: I had to change your code slightly: `ImageField imageField = item.Fields[fieldName];
            return Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);`

Comment: `MediaItem mediaItem = item.Fields[fieldName].Item;` should return the original Item. I think you have to use `Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField` here.

Answer (score 1):

you have to supply it with the Model that your sending back to your view from the controller:

something like :

Model:

```
public class c1
{

public string mediaUrl{ get {return Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaURL();}

}
```

Controller:

```
ActionResult View1()
{
//prepare you View Values
return View(c1);
}
```

View:

```
//the required field should look like this

<a href='@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.mediaUrl))'> Link to File </a>
```

regards

Comment: Is a custom model the only way of doing it? The knowledge base for Razor syntax for Sitecore MVC isn't that great.

Comment: I dont know if its the best way to do it, but I've been doing MVC for 4 years and thats always what I use and plus you'll have more control over it with loosely coupled views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the Raw value of Media or Field using `HtmlString` before using it in Rendering when using with `FieldRenderer`.

Though if you can provide more code then it can be answered more accurately because in Sitecore there are many ways (Sitecore ORMs and/or APIs) using which you can render Item Fields.

Also refer this [Sitecore MVC project](https://github.com/Sitecore-Community/sample-sitecore-mvc) on GitHub and below listed Sitecore MVC videos on YouTube it can prove helpful in long run.

1. [Sitecore MVC - Getting Started (Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Mwcphtz4w)
2. [Sitecore MVC -- View Renderings, @Html.Sitecore(), and Custom Models (Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW_rQp9bMmE)

And there few [blog articles](http://mhwelander.net/category/sitecore-mvc/) by Martina they are good resource on Sitecore MVC parts.

I hope that will be helpful.

Please ask if anything else.