# Rendering images by id using Sitecore 7 MVC and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I've got a checklist whose data source is a folder in the Sitecore Media Library.  Each of the 'checked' items in this field represents an image in this folder, so I'm expecting this checklist to compile into a string of pipe-delimited image ids.  Is it possible to use these ids to render the Media Library images on a View?

This is an example of my ViewModel:

```
public class PageViewModel {
    public List<string> ImageIDs { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an example of my Razor syntax code:

```
@foreach (var imageId in PageViewModel.ImageIDs) {
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="@Url.Content(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageId.MediaItem))">
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Sitecore CheckList is a Multilist under the covers. So you can treat it as such.

```
public class PageViewModel {
    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }
}
```

Parse the field into url strings

```
MultilistField related = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Related Images"];

List<string> imageUrls;

foreach(var item in related.GetItems())
{
    string hashedUrl = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item));

    imageUrls.Add(hashedUrl);
}

var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel {ImageUrls = imageUrls};
```

Finally your view

```
@foreach (var imageUrl in PageViewModel.ImageIDs) {
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="@imageUrl">
    </div>
}
```

The images will not be editable. You can only display them.

Comment: 2 issues with this. First - only the image url is required, we don't need to pass the entire item to the view, so get the Url in the controller. It will make the razorscript cleaner. Second, you should run the image Url through the `HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url)` method in case you want to add resizing attributes etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `MediaManager` does, but your `imageId` is a string and you are accessing a `MediaItem` property, which would be incorrect, unless you have an extension method on a string.

Your approach seems correct, but not knowing the API, I would take a guess and say that it should be:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageId))">
```

UPDATE

Did a little digging around and it seems that you can write an extension method that will take in a string and get you the media.

Take a look:
[Get media url in View in Sitecore MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828908/get-media-url-in-view-in-sitecore-mvc)

Comment: This won't work because `GetMediaUrl()` only accepts a `MediaItem` object as a parameter - I think that the approach that I was taking is intuitive but wildly incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

```
@model RotatorViewModel 

<h1>Products List</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.RotatorItems)
{
  <h2>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Title", item)</h2>
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Image", item)
      @Html.Sitecore().Field("Description", item)
}
```

Comment: It would be worth explaining _why_ you feel this code solves the OP's problem.